# Install MDM profile via SafariViewController

Tags: ios, mdm, sfsafariviewcontroller

I was wondering is there a way to install the profile(.mobileconfig) via SafariViewController. I'm aware that only Mail.app and Safari.app have the privileges of doing so.

So, if there is way that SafariViewController can handle such request, please let me know.

Thanks,
Yathish

Comment: Have you attempted to navigate to a link containing a profile to test this?

Comment: Yes. Nothing happens in SafariViewController  when navigated to the link where the profile has been hosted.. But opening the same link in Safari, download the profile and ask the user to install

Comment: Well, like @Harshavardhan mentioned, then it looks like you don't have the capability to do it, but opening a link in Safari will accomplish this (though of course will send your user out of your app which isn't idea).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the documents written for SafariViewController(https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SafariServices/Reference/SFSafariViewController_Ref/index.html), are saying that the SafariViewController is minimizing the work of developers who need to create UIWebView inside the application which need to show the web interface in application.

On the other side Safari.app is a different iceland where things are going on, and our application is a different one. Apple granted different level of permissions to applications. Based on that the Mail.app and the Safari.app are enabled to install the .mobileconfig(configuration files).

As we Apple is very much clear about the functionality of the SafariViewController, they will not allow us to install the .mobileconfig file from out applications with SafariViewController.

Comment: I was hoping the same. Thanks for the response

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's possible to install mobile configuration profiles (.mobileconfig) via SFSafariViewController since iOS 11.3. I confirmed this on both iOS 11.3 and iOS 12 beta.

See here for more details: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/103337